# coordinates stored in a getPoint() object

Tags: java

I am having a problem with the following code. My intent is to store the coordinates of a mouse click into an arraylist using getPoint, and then draw a rectangle at each location that the user has clicked. I have searched high and low for how to extract the x and y coordinates individually from a getPoint object to no avail. I am new to java, the line that is giving me trouble at compile time is:

g2.drawRect(coordinateList(j).getHeight(),coordinateList(j.getWidth(),3,3);

I know that I am probably way off, but how can I extract the x and y coordinates of a point individually from an array list, one item of the array by one in order to repaint a rectangle at the new click point and also all the previous clicks as well?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.*;

public class ClickCloud extends JPanel
{
    private int pointxy;
    //private Rectangle2D.Double r1;
    private boolean mouseClick;
    private int count;
    //private Point[] points;
    private Point coordinates = new Point(0, 0);
    private ArrayList<Point> coordinateList = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public ClickCloud() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        this.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; 
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
          RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
            g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            g2.drawRect(coordinateList(j).getHeight(),coordinateList(j.getWidth(),3,3);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) { 
            count++;
            coordinates.setLocation(me.getPoint());
            coordinateList.add(coordinates.getLocation());
            repaint();
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) { }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) { }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) { }
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ClickCloud demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.add(new ClickCloud());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);        
    }
}
```

Thanks,

T

Answer (score 3):

Forget all the `getLocation` and `setLocation`.  It's redundant.  Just store `me.getPoint()` in your `coordinateList`.

Then you can get the `x` and `y` coordinates with `point.getX()` and `point.getY()` respectively.

In `paintComponent`, there is an easier way to iterate over a list of points:

```
for (Point coordinate : coordinateList) { //"for each coordinate in coordinateList"
   //do something with coordinate.getX() and coordinate.getY()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, clearly I have no idea how to post code properly in a comment. Bear with me please.

Comment: Great, looks like this is definitely getting somewhere, the problem now is that the getX() and getY() are giving double values, where the drawRect requires only ints. So I assume I have to change these values to ints first. Can I do this directly in my paintComponent method?
'code'
    for (Point coordinate : coordinateList) {
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        g2.drawRect(coordinate.getX(),coordinate.getY(),3,3);
    }
}
'code'
Thanks,

T

Comment: @user2129525: regarding, `"How do I wrap code in a comment to show it properly?"` -- you don't. Comments are for comments only. If you want to show updated code, edit your original post, add the new code and related text to the bottom of your question leaving the original code and text in place, and then post a comment with whomever is helping you to let them know to look at the updated question.

Comment: @user2129525: You can cast a double to an int like this: `int x = (int) coordinate.getX();`

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting properly the points from the ArrayList.

```
g2.drawRect(coordinateList(j).getHeight(),coordinateList(j.getWidth(),3,3);
```

To get the item at index `j` with an ArrayList, you simply use the method `get()`:

```
Point point = coordinateList.get(j);
```

Then the problem is that `point`only represents, well, points... They only have X and Y coordinates, not width and height. If I try to guess what you want to do and assume that you want to draw 3x3 rectangles where the user has clicked, you would call `drawRect()` like this:

```
g2.drawRect(point.getX(), point.getY(), 3, 3);
```

Also:

- You don't need to handle a `count` variable to know the number of points you have in your ArrayList. Just use the size() method of coordinateList or even better, use an [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with).
- You can use MouseAdapter instead of MouseListener to only override the events you need.
- You don't need the `coordinates` member and the get/setLocation stuff. Just write `coordinateList.add(me.getPoint());`